# Maven assembly plugin different filters for the same execution

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

Is there any way I can use different filters for the same execution?
For example in addition to common consumer filter below I would like to have additional filters applied to each environment

```
<execution>
    <id>consumer</id>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <finalName>consumer</finalName>
        <filters>
            <filter>src/main/resources/consumer/filter.properties</filter>
        </filters>
        <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/main/resources/consumer/tc.xml</descriptor>
            <descriptor>src/main/resources/consumer/dev.xml</descriptor>
            <descriptor>src/main/resources/consumer/qa.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

Comment: Which files would you like to filter etc. ?